# How to use multiple JasperReports Server instances with one Postgresql DB?

Tags: jasperserver

How to use multiple JasperReports server instances with only one centralized Postgresql DB? Another words - let say I have Win server1, Win server2, Win server3 and Win server4.

On windows servers1,2 and 3 I need to install only JasperReport server (Tomcat) with no Postgresql DB, but on windows server 4 I want to install only Postgresql DB.

All Jasper server instances from servers 1,2 and 3 will connect to only one centralized Postgresql DB on win server4. Is it doable?

Answer (score 0):

It is doable and fairly well documented, best is to review Jaspersoft documentation for designing a cluster, documentation is available in the [Jaspersoft Community Docs section](http://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/jasperreports-server-ultimate-guide/v55/designing-cluster) for registered users. It outlines common architecture of a JasperReports Server cluster, utilizing a load balancer for application and one shared repository database in the backend. Database operations are thread-safe, use case in doc maps your case:

- install one DB
- point all JRS applications to this DB
- review recommendations on scheduler configuration to avoid that all nodes simultaneously trigger scheduled jobs